# Does ssh have an option to query the signature of a server without logging in first?

Tags: ssh

For reasons of security does ssh have an option to query the signature of a server without logging in first, ie execute a command like:

`ssh --getkey host.example.com`

Comment: No, but you could `ssh-keyscan(1)` first and then hand your credentials off to whomever.

Comment: how about nc server 22

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> `ssh-keyscan` is a utility for gathering the  public ssh host keys of a number of hosts.
>
> For scanning,
>   one does not need login  access to the machines that are being
>   scanned, nor  does the scanning  process involve any encryption.

The command is part of the openssh client.